# Macro for taking the middle value of a string from a closed workbook doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

One of problems I have is that, when I want to e.g. just map the middle of a string from other workbook, it doesn't work. In the cell it needs to take that middle value there is afterwards nothing, and I get REF! error. When I do the same thing without recording macro, it works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Data\DA1\Korr\Makros\akt_5.9\Output\account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx")
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 0
    End With
    Windows("record_count_check.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=MID(INDEX('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1,MAX(('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1<>"""")*ROW('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1))),21,3)"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=RIGHT(INDEX('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2,MAX(('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2<>"""")*ROW('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2))),10)"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2)"
```

What I need to do? How is the best way to code so that I'm able to access data from other workbooks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "In the cell it needs to take that middle value there is afterwards nothing, and I get REF! error.". Can you rephrase that sentence?

Comment: Well, basically what I'm trying to do is following: I have a number of tables, and for each table I need to watch the last row, first of column A, and then of column B-meaning that in my table I have the first column-which is the name of the table- the second column is what I look in the table - column A, and third column is that what I look in the table but in column B..So basically, in that first column after the macro has finished its thing-there is nothing, basically blank (but when u click on the cell, in the formula bar you can see the formula) and in the next column there is error REF!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to ge values from another workbook, then you need to include the workbook and the sheet name in the formula. In your VBA, none of the functions include the name of the worksheet, just the workbook name and the cell address.

Also you need to be using the same cell address mode, i.e. R1C1 style or A1 style. If you are using `FormulaR1C1` then you must use the R1C1 style.

For example,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2)"
```

Should be something like:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA([account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx]sheet_name!R2C3)"
```

EDIT: I've just realised that `account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx` is the name of the workbook into which you are putting the formula. You can remove the the name of the workbook from the formula then.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C3)"
```

You can always manually build the formula in the worksheet, select the cell and then in the Immediate window in the IDE enter "?Selection.FormulaR1C1" (without the quotes), press Enter to see what answer you get.

[image: Immediate window in IDE]

Comment: No, this formula works perfectly fine..the problem lies in the above two..
I've tried applying your proposal, but it's even worse-again an error '1004'-unable to set the FormulaArray property..

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: No it is not.. im putting the formula into record_count_check.xlsm.. and taking the values from that other workbook..

Comment: Understood. The bit about R1C1 and including sheet name is still valid though.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, but we're focusing on the wrong things here.. and as regards to sheet name-I've tried it, and its returning and error...however, this counta forula is working fine..the problem is with the two array formulas..they are not working-meaning when I record them as a macro, they do not return values..

Comment: What do the array formulas look like if you type them manually into the sheet so that they work? Maybe add that to your original question.

Comment: It's the same as above in the code: =MID(INDEX('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1,MAX(('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1<>"""")*ROW('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1))),21,3)

Comment: Can you explain what this bit does? `MAX(('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C2<>"""")*ROW('account-acc-std-mit-lineal.xlsx'!C1))` I don't understand why you are using MAX function when there is only one value.

Comment: the formula is OK, the formula works.. the question here is just how to use the data from other closed workbooks and not to get an error

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32148792/4243498) for similar question & answer. I don't get how your functions work without the sheet name being included in the formula so cannot help further.